# Kibana 7.17.5 Not Recognizing Monitoring Data

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, monitoring

I updated Elastic Search and Kibana last week from 7.6.2 to 7.17.5. When doing so, the Stack Monitoring page within Kibana broke. I was previously using a legacy exporter for sending the logs from my Elastic Search cluster to my Kibana/Monitoring cluster.

After diving down many rabbit holes I installed metricbeat and got it to export logs to the monitoring cluster at .monitoring-es-7-mb-*. To no avail, Kibana still shows an empty Stack Monitoring page.

Does anyone have any idea of what I should check to try and get the monitoring logs to show up on the Stack Monitoring page?

Comment: Can you confirm that 1) you installed Metricbeat 7.17.5 (same version, not the latest 8.3 version) and 2) `.monitoring-es-7-mb-*` actually contains data?

Comment: dang! I thought you were onto something with the metric beat version, but my machines do have metric beat 7.17.5-1 and yes there is data in the `.monitoring-es-7-mb-*` index. They contain things like `agent.type: metricbeat`, `event.module: elasticsearch`, and some node information like `node_stats.indices.segments.doc_values_in_bytes: 1,479,002`